# modal box needs to be stuck to the right side of the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal box of bootstrap; I want it to be stuck to the right side of the screen with resealable ability  based on the windows size and the min-width needs to be 500px; I tried the follwoing but when I resize the window it does not work :( could you please help me in thsi regard!

```
<div id='test' style="float: right">
    <div id="add_pixel" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
</div>

#add_pixel{
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: right;

    min-width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: fixed` with `right: 0` to achieve desired result.

Comment: Do you mean for id= test or add_pixel? I tried both and neither worked!

Comment: I mean for `#add_pixel`. It should make it flow on the right side of screen and ignore scrolling.